# Ace and IE: editable content cutting off at 2nd line of code

Tags: internet-explorer, ace-editor, browser-feature-detection

Edit SOLVED:
Initially I got under the impression that Ace will be completely unusable due to editable code cutting off on 2nd line. So I thought 'let's not even load it in IE'. Turns our the bug was fixed, Ace works just fine in 9 (or close enough, not quite as nice as in FF or Chrome though).

ORIGINAL QUESTION:
I find myself having to prevent Ace editor from loading in IE  and wonder what specific browser features need detection?
Trying to avoid browser sniffing.

Comment: why do you have to prevent Ace editor from loading on IE?
it should work fine on ie8+

Comment: "Should" does not mean it does. When I try to view the kitchen sink demo, source code cuts off at the top on line 2. Similar thing happens when I try to implement it for for what I need.

Comment: I mean if it doesn't work, it's a bug/regression in Ace, which is not detectable by browser features.
source code cuts off at the top on line 2 is fixed in latest master see http://ajaxorg.github.com/ace-builds/kitchen-sink.html

Comment: Hm... nice. So is it a demo fix? Do you know where it's mentioned in the change or commit log(s)?

Comment: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/commit/2bdd35a00424f9c2d27e2631f140217d9ca4ddb1#lib/ace/keyboard/textinput.js https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/1238

Comment: Hmmmmmmm... my apologies for snarkness. If you can make an answer from your comments I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browser feature detection can't work for this, because ace already does feature detection, and when it's broken, it's broken in a rather subtle way, because of a bug in ace code, not because of missing browser features.

So the best way is either to report a bug or use browser version sniffing.